# Interval specified with little oh notation

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

In [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82463813.pdf) which deals with ordered factorizations, I found approximation formulae for the number of ordered factorizations of integer $n$ into $m$ distinct parts greater than one. In the paper it is stated:

*If $1 \leq m = o(\sqrt{log(x)})$, then:*
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:smallm}
A(x, m) = x \frac{(\log(x))^{m - 1}}{(m - 1)!} e^{-\frac{((1 - \gamma)m + 1)(m - 1)}{\log(x)}} 
\left(1 + O\left(\frac{m^3}{(\log(x))^2}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
*uniformly in $m$.*

I am not sure how to interpret $1 \leq m = o(\sqrt{log(x)})$ expression, and I do not understand what uniformly in $m$ means.

Since the formula gives an approximation for the number of $m$-factorizations for all $n \leq x$, I compared the results given with the formula to the actual number $m$-factorizations obtained with enumeration. I assumed that $m$ is in interval $[1, \lfloor\sqrt{log(x)}\rfloor]$. This seemed to yield good results. In other words, I assumed that $1 \leq m = o(\sqrt{log(x)}) \implies [1, \lfloor\sqrt{log(x)}\rfloor]$. Is this true, and if not for
which $m$ does the expression for $A(x, m)$ hold?

Any comments or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This is not correct. The assumption $1 \leq m = o(\sqrt{\log x})$ means that if $m$ varies with $x$ in such a way that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{m}{\sqrt{\log x}} = 0$, then the desired asymptotic for $A(x,m)$ holds. You can think of this as saying that $m$ may grow with $x$ but at a rate slower than $\sqrt{\log x}$.

Comment: @Peter Humphries Let say that x is fixed to 1024. For which values of m does the expression for A(x, m) hold?

Comment: Any fixed $m$. Your question doesn't really make sense: implicit in this asymptotic is the understanding that $x$ is tending to infinity. The result is this asymptotic behaviour of $A(x,m)$ as $x$ tends to infinity remains valid if $m$ also tends to infinity ast $x \to \infty$ (so think of $m$ as a function of $x$) provided that $m$ grows more slowly than $\sqrt{\log x}$ in the sense that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{m}{\sqrt{\log x}} = 0$.

Comment: I am aware that I do not understand this. My aim was to use this expression for approximation of the number of $m$-factorizations of integers up to $x$. Does this make sense? Moreover, what confused me was that in the paper they differ two cases for $A(x, m)$, i.e., for small $m$ such that $1 \leq m = o(\sqrt{log(x)})$, and large $m$ such that $\sqrt{log(x)} \leq m \leq log_2(x)$. Therefore, I thought that the former implies the interval.

Comment: Theorem 2 states an asymptotic for $m = o((\log x)^{3/5})$, while Theorem 3 is contained in the range $m \geq \sqrt{\log x}$. These overlap. However, Corollary 3 does not overlap with Theorem 3. If you are interested in the case where $m$ does *not* change as $x$ gets larger, then this is covered by Theorem 2 and Corollary 3. The point is that the answer depends on how large $m$ is with respect to $x$ as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Is it correct to calculate $A(x, m)$ using Theorem 2. for $m \leq \sqrt{log(x)}$ and using Theorem 3. $m \geq \sqrt{log(x)}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct so long as $m$ isn't too large (Theorem 3 has some restrictions on how large $m$ can be relative to $x$).